# Cannot access variable outside function in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript, functional-programming, scope

I have two functions which return a value.

```
protected function createbox():player
            {
                    var face:player = _world.CreateBody(bodydef);

        return face;

            }
```

They are identical except that they return a different variable. One returns face, the other returns eyes.

They are executed like this:

```
_elements.push(new Item(createbox(), new BoxSprite()));
```

The elements are created. But the problem comes when I try to referece face or eyes. I don't know how to reference them. They don't appear in the debug list of variables. They are null value (outside their functions).

Item is a class file. Which is also a function

```
public function Item(body:player,sprite:Graphic)
```

`_elements` is a vector array.
`player` is a class

I don't know the syntax to access face and eyes. They always return NULL or property not found no matter where you access them.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Global variable. A global variable is available both inside and outside the function definition. So try assigning the variable out of the function and updating its value inside the function.

See example:

```
var face:String = "This is created out of the function"; 
function scopeTest(){ 
    face = "This was updated inside the function";
} 
scopeTest(); 
trace(face);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your post, *faces* and *eyes* are return objects from *createbox()*, which then are involved in the instantiation process of an *Item* object, which then is pushed into the *_elements* vector. Therefore, in order to access *faces* and *eyes*, you have to pass these objects to some public references during the constructor of the *Item* class. After that, you should be able to access them by enumerating wanted *Item* objects in the vector and using dot syntax on the *Item* objects.